# How can I export multiple objects into one json file?

Tags: uv, export, three.js

I have downloaded a car model which consists of 1 car body and 4 tires for a simple game development.(totally 5 objects)

Although it's no problem to separately export each object with UV mapping information in json file ,how can I export them at the same time into one json file?

[image: the car with 4 tire objects]

Comment: What do you mean by a "tier"? There are 5 meshes, and the three.js Blender exporter is only exporting one at a time?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error , it should be "tire". I haven't known the way to export more than one object at a time until half a hour ago, but now I knew about  something like group objects , and I am going to give it a try!

Comment: Grouping the objects didn't solve my problem , and so was all select function(keyboard:a).After I exported , it was still only one object which displayed with white font in the outliner winodw.

Comment: I'd try the [Blender glTF exporter](https://github.com/khronosgroup/gltf-blender-exporter) and [THREE.GLTFLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/loaders/GLTFLoader).